# Properly saving XDocument

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a custom data service in my website , which is supposed to refresh data every 10 minutes without any downtime for users. ( asp.net mvc3 , mssql 2008 , c# )

At the moment it's refreshing data every 10 minutes and updating my database ( mssql ) no problem. But the thing is ,  instead of reading data off db for every user request , I want to save it to a XML file right after refreshing data so users can get it without any extra db connection or process.

So there will be one process regathering data and writing to XML meanwhile lots of user will be requesting that XML every second.

Since I don't know much about File Write/Read stuff , I'm not sure if I should lock file before writing it , because other processes may be reading it. Or maybe it's OK since just one process will be writing and others reading/requesting it won't create any problems? Also not sure if the Save function of XDocument already has lock before writing in it.

So , all in all ; how can i safely save my XDocument objet into a xml file while any other processes may be reading/requesting that file?

OR should I just read data from Sql ( nevermind the process time&delay for every user) and return XDocument object , which would be easier I guess?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's a bad idea to write the XML out to a file - it might not even be faster to read it back than calling the DB. Instead I'd use the [ASP.NET caching infrastructure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hbbsfk6.aspx), i.e. using the `Cache` class to cache the data in memory - this will be much faster.

Comment: Oh yea now that makes sense , I'm not experienced in this stuff so I totally forgot about it. Looking into it now , thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have a database which is designed, tested and built to deliver data to the users, why do you want to save data out from it and implement your own file system based database?

I think the last option you have mentioned is the best, just connect to the database and retrieve the XML to the users as needed. If you have efficient queries and a solid DataAccessLayer the db will perform well.

Comment: Well yea it sounds a bit weirdto use xml while i already have a sql but I just thought there would be a better way than reading and processing data for every user , while the data is only refreshed every 10 minutes.

Comment: SQL Server knows it, it has his own cache system built in. .NET Framework also has the connection pool which is very fast in recycling a just closed connection and reuse it. As other said, you can then use the Cache object of ASP.NET and make it to expire every 10 minutes, or less, no need to do custom file I/O to implement your own wheel ( caching )

Answer (score 0):

Another option is using a caching mechanism such as memcache or AppFabric Cache.

Comment: Thank you too Eric but I had to accept BrokenGlass' answer as it was just a few seconds earlier :)